# Is the function $f(x=\sum a_n/2^n)=\sum na_n/2^n$ continuous and nowhere differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x=\sum_{1<=n<\inf}a_n/2^n$ be the binary expansion of a real number in [0,1]. Assume that infinitely many of a_n are 0 so that the expansion is unique.

Define $f(x)=\sum_{1<=n<\inf}na_n/2^n$.

Is f continuous?

Is f nowhere differentiable?

If both answers are positive, then it seems we find a particularly simple example of such functions, which seems to me very unlikely.

The function is indeed continuous and nondifferentiable at all points other than those of the form m/2^n

Comment: How do you express 1 in the series form with your requirement?

Comment: Here is link to the post on Mathematics Stack Exchange: [Is the function $f(x=\sum a_n/2^n)=\sum na_n/2^n$ continuous and nowhere differentiable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3161784)

Answer (score 2):

No, $f$ is not continuous.  Consider $x = 1/2$.  $f(1/2) = 1/2$ but $f(1/2 - 2^{-n}) > 2/4 + 3/8 = 7/8$ for $n > 3$. Similarly, $f$ is not continuous at any integer multiple of $2^{-n}$.